# How would I find the Unique Entries using the COUNT Formula?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, count-unique

I am looking to find the Total Number of users opted into certain campaigns (Columns G-J). I'm not sure if I am using the correct form of the Count/CountUnique/CountIf formula when calculating the amount.

I've tried the CountUnique for 1 of the columns but I'm not sure if that number is correct either.

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2qB5Uqs58VpLF58-XUKQd2UIns6yoNElp1FilwvL1A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cell **H2**:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, REGEXMATCH(D2:D, "Post.*"))))
```

cell **I2**:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B, REGEXMATCH(D2:D, "Trans.*"))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to be what i am looking for! To find the number for Cell G1, "Total Number Opted In to at least 1 Email" can I use the same formula you used except replace  "Post.*" with "Email.*"